# How to increase row height in Excel by X. ie. Add vertical cell padding

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have this report and I want to increase the vertical cell padding to make it easier to read.

Now, typically you could just select multiple rows and change the row height until you're satisfied.

However, in this case, I have cells with wrapped text and multiple lines. I can't change change the the row height, because the wrapped text will get cut off.

What I want to do is **increase** the row height of a bunch of cells by a certain value.
Rather than just change it to a specify value.
ie.

```
rowheight = rowheight + X
```

Not

```
rowheight = X
```

Can you do this in excel? Will I need VBA?

Comment: I'd guess you'll eventually have at least some VBA here. Therefore... I'd move this question to SO instead of keeping it here in SU.

Comment: I don't see any reason to. If VBA is required, your code is perfect. Just needs to be changed to use a selection rather than a static range.

Comment: IMO... SU: Excel-only tricks and functions. SO: Excel/VBA related tricks and functions.

Comment: I guess the point is that... I could've done it with VBA myself. I was looking for a answer from the perspective. If I asked at SO.... I -definitely- would've gotten a VBA answer.

Comment: So, your idea was to do it _without_ using VBA? If so, you should've been clearer in your question... Anyways, I don't believe it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the code below... not sure if there would be a way to apply it for all rows once. I'd be glad (and upvote)  if someone else here knows :)

```
Sub fixRowHeight()

Dim oRange As Excel.Range
Dim oRow As Excel.Range
Dim dblFactor As Double

Set oRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:B25")
dblFactor = 5

For Each oRow In oRange.Rows

    oRow.RowHeight = oRow.RowHeight + dblFactor

Next oRow

End Sub
```

Comment: While this is old, I still found this useful. I revised this version to include a check for the max row height of 409.5. Using this sub would run into an error if the added height exceeded the max row height. Below is what I added to For Each loop.

Comment: If oRow.RowHeight + dblFactor <= 409.5 Then
    oRow.RowHeight = oRow.RowHeight + dblFactor
Else
    oRow.RowHeight = 409.5
End If

Answer (score 8):

I've just hit this issue *and* the above solution is not satisfactory in some circumstances.

1. Insert a column somewhere - probably column A.  Select the entire column.
2. Give it top/bottom borders of the thickest kind - the solid fat bar - apply/ok.
3. Select all other columns that you'd like to be padded.  Vertically center them.
4. Hide the bordered column & save.

This gives you a top and bottom padding of approximately 3 units/5px top & bottom. With arial, it's enough to keep tops and tails from touching the cell edges.

The VBA code provided is good.  But it fails as soon as your spreadsheet is viewed by someone who needs to narrow up some columns and so removes manual formatting or applies their own. If the user knows what they're doing, they will hit Ctrl + A and double click a row indicator to auto-height all rows.

Using the borders provides a solution that will always work regardless, unless manually formatted away.

Comment: Very clever! Works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

To expound [on the answer](https://superuser.com/a/317676/165766) from [Tiago Cardoso](https://superuser.com/users/68714/tiago-cardoso), I added a condition to check to make sure the maximum row height is not exceeded when increasing the row height with the resize factor variable.

```
Sub FixRowHeight()
    Dim oRange As Excel.Range
    Dim oRow As Excel.Range
    Dim dblFactor As Double

    Set oRange = Sheets(1).Range("A1:O367")
    dblFactor = 12

    For Each oRow In oRange.Rows
        If oRow.RowHeight + dblFactor <= 409.5 Then
            oRow.RowHeight = oRow.RowHeight + dblFactor
        Else
            oRow.RowHeight = 409.5
        End If
    Next oRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a macro to help you out.

First it sets the vertical alignment for each cell to `Center`.

Next, it takes the *current height* of each cell and adds **7.5** to it (this is equivalent to **10 pixels**). In the end, it adds a 5-pixel padding to the top and bottom part of the cell. Just adjust this value according to your preference.

```
Sub PadCells()

Set cr = Selection

For Each cr In cr.Rows
    newHeight = cr.RowHeight + 7.5 
    cr.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    cr.RowHeight = newHeight
Next cr

End Sub
```

**To use:**

1. Select the cells for which you want to adjust the height.
2. Run the macro.

Comment: Threw an error for me on this line: cr.rowHeight = newHeight -- "Unable to set the RowHeight property of the Range class"